# Issues with USB Devices and Hard Drives

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, usb

Few weeks ago I built a new PC (Spec below). Nearly everything worked fine so far with that pc, but when I first wanted to use the Hard drive from an older PC I noticed, that it didn't show up in "This PC". As I didn't use that HDD for a longer time I expected, that this is caused by a linux file system perhaps. So I formatted that drive and it worked find, but when I tried later to use an external HDD with NTFS as filesystem I noticed that is doesn't show up in "This PC" as well. So I had a look in Disk Management and there I found out that my PC doesn't recognize that this HDD has a filesystem. So that column is empty for this drive, although it shows me the partitions of that drive. I don't know what is the reason for this behaviour. I think there is no fault at the drive itself, as it works fine at other PCs.

The second issue I noticed is, that sometimes I have issues with my USB devices. One device (a Mooltipass Mini) for example doesn't work in most cases when I attach it to a USB hub, it works in most cases when I use the USB ports at the front of my PC case but there as well sometimes while using it it get somehow "disconnected".

I have absolutely no clue what could be the reason for this two issues, but I hope somebody here can help me.

The Specs of my PC:

- 500GB Samsung 850 EVO SSD
- 32 GB HyperX DDR4-2400 RAM
- Asus GeForce GTX1070 STRIX OC GAMING Graphics card
- Intel Core i7-7700K CPU
- Asus STRIX Z270E Gaming Mainboard
- 500W Ocz Power Supply
- 1 Seagate HDD
- 1 Bluray Drive
- 1 DVD Burner

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a driver issue with the chipset.  I would try reinstalling the chipset from the manufacturer's website.  If that doesn't work, I have had phenomenal luck with Driver Reviver: https://www.reviversoft.com/driver-reviver/

Comment: Unfortunatly that didn't work. So I updated to the lates Chipset driver, but the issues remain.